# GUI Download manager needed for Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, gui, download-manager, idm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Download manager for Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/79290/download-manager-for-ubuntu)

What is the best GUI downlaod manager? 
 I need something that looks like IDM for Windows

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://askubuntu.com/q/47628/ http://askubuntu.com/q/32850/ http://askubuntu.com/q/54837/ http://askubuntu.com/q/47047/ http://askubuntu.com/q/170022